# KSH shell if statement -a option

Tags: shell, ksh

I want to convert the following if statement to java, could someone explain to me what `-a -a 5-lt 2` means. Is `-a` is like `and`?

```
if [ 4 -gt `echo "2+(3/2)" |bc` -a 5-lt 2]; then
```

Thank you
Azad

Comment: It's not an argument to `if` at all, it's an argument to `[`, which is a separate command.

Comment: I am not quick understanding it. So, what does "-a  5-lt 2" means?

Comment: It has no meaning; it's invalid syntax and doesn't work.

Comment: ...now, if you mean `-a 5 -lt 2`, with the spaces, that means "and 5 is numerically less than 2", but it's a deprecated syntax that isn't supposed to be used.

Comment: ...the POSIX-compliant syntax is more like `if [ 4 -gt "$(echo "2+(3/2)" | bc)" ] && [ 5 -lt 2 ]; then` -- **with** all the spaces; none of them are optional.

Comment: ...whereas modern syntax for ksh or bash is more like `if (( 4 > "$(echo "2+(3/2)" | bc)" && 5 < 2 ))`.

Comment: See BashPitfalls #10 at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#if_.5Bbar.3D.22.24foo.22.5D.3B_then_... -- actually, you might do well to read the whole document.

Comment: Thank you, I understanding now.